# Default file to upload for fileuploader?

Tags: php, html

Is it somehow possible to trick a PHP fileupload to select a text document from the server?

Maybe by giving a link to the file in `value="link-to-file.txt"` in the HTML formular?

Comment: Depends what you're doing. If you are using user input to select a filename then YES any server accessible to the web server user is potentially fair game, and you _must_ carefully filter the input against patterns like `../` or null bytes, and when possible use a value whitelist.

Comment: Incidentally the name of the things you need to protect yourself against are [_Directory Traversal Attack_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) and [_NULL byte injection_](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246949/Null%20Byte%20Injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple steps to distinguish:

1. The browsers sends data to the webserver
2. PHP interprets this data, stores the file content in a temporary file and makes an entry in $_FILES
3. Your script does something with the array received in $_FILES and the content in the temporary file

As PHP and its beholding webservers are usually widely used, steps 1 and 2 should not allow the attacker to do bad things. The most vulnerable step is 3. The contents here can be manipulated by the attacker - and if you, e.g., use the filename to name the target-file on your server, this is dangerous without appropriate filtering.